# Conditional rendering in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm following the Absolute Beginners Series on Channel9 and we've been told to implement some features that are not presented in the series, just as a challenge to learn something else.

What we have is a `DataTemplate` used to build some "tiles"-like controls and we use them in a `LongListSelector`.

What I need to do is to add a context menu to those tiles to perform some extra operations on them.

Now, one of those operations must be performed only on a certain type of tile, depending on which was the collection bound to the `LongListSelector`.

Here's the page code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SoundBoard.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/SampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SoundTileDataTemplate">            
            <Grid Name="TileGrid" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="0,0,12,12">
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.PinToStartMessage, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem IsEnabled="False" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.DeleteSoundMessage, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,6,6,0">
                    <Ellipse Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                    <Image Source="/Assets/AppBar/Play.png"></Image>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="6,0,0,6"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <MediaElement Name="AudioPlayer" Volume="1"/>

        <phone:Pivot Title="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
            <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Animals.Title}">    
                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Animals.Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="150,150" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SoundTileDataTemplate}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Cartoons.Title}">

                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Cartoons.Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="150,150" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SoundTileDataTemplate}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Taunts.Title}">
                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Taunts.Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="150,150" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SoundTileDataTemplate}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Warnings.Title}">               
                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Warnings.Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="150,150" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SoundTileDataTemplate}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding CustomSounds.Title}">                
                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomSounds.Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="150,150" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SoundTileDataTemplate}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>

    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Now, what I need to do is to enable the second `Toolkit:MenuItem` only when the control is loaded in the last `LongListSelector`.

Is it possible to write a boolean expression in the item's `IsEnabled` that returns true if the items of the `DataTemplate` have the `CustomSounds` type or do I need to write two different `DataTemplate` to handle this situation?

EDIT:
I've changed some code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Name="SBMainPage"
...
    <toolkit:MenuItem IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsDeleteEnabled, ElementName=SBMainPage}" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.DeleteSoundMessage, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Tap="DeleteSoundHandler"/>
```

but now the boolean value returned by `IsDeleteEnabled` property is never updated, so it takes the `false` that is given when the property is read the first time and it never changes it!

Answer (score 0):

A converter will do what you want:

```
class TypeToBoolConverter :IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.GetType() == typeof(CustomSounds);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and that you can use:

```
<toolkit:MenuItem IsEnabled="{Binding ,Converter={StaticResource myTypeConverter}}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that IsDeleteEnabled adheres to INotifyPropertyChanged. Frankly that is what I do/have done by simply adding a status flag boolean on the Model View and hooking up page logic by binding.